# How to fix the issue with Node Js backend only executing the first controller?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, mean-stack

In my Book review site in the search option the user can search for books either by `author` name or the `genre`. For those I have separate functions in the `search.service.ts` below. There are separate controllers in the backend too. But while searching, it only executes the first controller, it doesn't execute the second controller even though the route is directing towards it.

Here is `search.service.ts` functions,

```
getPostsByAuthor(author: string) {
  this.http.get<{message: string, posts: any, maxPosts: number }>(BACKEND_URL + 'api/search/' + author)
  .pipe(map((postData) => {
    console.log(postData);
    return { posts: postData.posts.map((post) => {
      return {
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content,
        author: post.author,
        genre: post.genre,
        id: post._id,
        imagePath: post.imagePath,
        creator: post.creator
      };
    }),
    maxPosts: postData.maxPosts};
  }))
  .subscribe(transformedPostsData => {
    this.posts = transformedPostsData.posts;
    return this.posts;
  });
}

getPostsByGenre(genre: string) {
  this.http.get<{message: string, posts: any, maxPosts: number }>(BACKEND_URL + 'api/search/' + genre)
  .pipe(map((postData) => {
    console.log('Genre_');
    console.log(postData);
    return { posts: postData.posts.map((post) => {
      return {
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content,
        author: post.author,
        genre: post.genre,
        id: post._id,
        imagePath: post.imagePath,
        creator: post.creator
      };
    }),
    maxPosts: postData.maxPosts};
  }))
  .subscribe(transformedPostsData => {
    this.posts = transformedPostsData.posts;
    return this.posts;
  });
}
```

The route in `app.js`,

```
app.use('/api/search', searchRoutes);
```

The `search.js` in the route folder,

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const SearchController = require('../controllers/search');

router.get("/:author", SearchController.getPostsByAuthor);

router.get("/:Genre", SearchController.getPostsByGenre);

module.exports = router;
```

Here are the controllers consecutively given,

```
const Post = require('../models/post');
const User = require('../models/user');

exports.getPostsByAuthor = (req, res, next) => {
  let maxPosts = 10;
  Post.find({ author: req.params.author }).then(posts => {
    if(posts) {
      res.status(200).json({
        posts,
        message: "Post was successful",
        max: maxPosts
      });
    } else {
      res.status(500).alert('Not Found, double check the spelling').json({
        message: "Failed to get User Post"
      });
    }
  });
}

exports.getPostsByGenre = (req, res, next) => {
  let maxPosts = 10;
  Post.find({ genre: req.params.genre }).then(posts => {
    if(posts) {
      res.status(200).json({
        posts,
        message: "Post  weirdo successful",
        max: maxPosts
      });
    } else {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Failed to get User Post"
      });
    }
  });
}
```

It always runs the first one that means `getPostsByAuthor`, it never runs the second one.

I have checked by changing order, when I did put the `getPostsByGenre` in the first position then that was run and `getPostsByAuthor` did not run as it was placed second in order.

The controller placed in the first position in order, returns data perfectly, that means the route is reaching the `controller` file.

I'm not getting what's the issue. Did not find similar questions in SO.

I'm still new to development with MEAN stack, minimum of the clues would mean great help. Thank you.

Comment: in `exports.getPostsByGenre` function, should you use `User.find` instead of `Post.find`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just tried, it did not work. :-/

Comment: If I understand correctly you want both, `getPostsByAuthor` and `getPostsByGenre` routes to be executed?

Comment: No, the user either searches by author or the genre. Both have separate buttons with separate events which trigger separate functions, but not at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're trying to achieve routing is **wrong**.

When client makes a `GET` requests to route `/api/search`, express is going to look if a `GET` route is defined for the path. It will execute the first route it finds, in this case `router.get("/:author", SearchController.getPostsByAuthor)` (which you've mounted it first).

This is because middlewares are mounted like stack, execute first middleware then next and so forth.

You would need to define two different routes, since they are `GET` requests to two different resources, something like:

```
const SearchController = require('../controllers/search');

router.get("/author/:author", SearchController.getPostsByAuthor);

router.get("/genre/:Genre", SearchController.getPostsByGenre);

app.use('/api/search', searchRoutes);
```

Then you can call like:

```
api/search/author/someName

api/search/genre/someGenre
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir for you detailed explanation. It helped me to learn a lot and also it fixed the thing.